# Filter duplicate records and join them in other records - ORACLE

Tags: oracle

[image]

I want to filter duplicate the 'PDLINEGROUP' value,and then making them join in other records(Require:date is latest).

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you to pick up the line with latest date.

```
    SELECT 
       DISTINCT M.PDLINEGROUP, 
       G.MAX_CREATED_DATE 
    FROM ${YOUR_TABLE_NAME} M
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
               PDLINEGROUP, 
               MAX(CREATEDATE), --this will ensure to pick up the latest date
        FROM ${YOUR_TABLE_NAME} G
        GROUP BY PDLINEGROUP ON M.PDLINEGROUP=G.PDLINEGROUP 
    )
```